# A serious problem with 2 or more ADC of ATmega16

Tags: adc, c, atmega, noise, codevision

I have enabled 2 ADC of my microcontroller but there is a lot of noise. I mean when ADC(0) is enabled, everything is good but after enabling ADC(1)  the noise kick in.

Here is my code:

```
Chip type : ATmega16
Program type : Application
AVR Core Clock frequency: 16/000000 MHz
Memory model : Small
External RAM size : 0
Data Stack size : 256
*****************************************************/

#include <mega16.h>

#include <delay.h>

#ifndef RXB8
#define RXB8 1
#endif

#ifndef TXB8
#define TXB8 0
#endif

#ifndef UPE
#define UPE 2
#endif

#ifndef DOR
#define DOR 3
#endif

#ifndef FE
#define FE 4
#endif

#ifndef UDRE
#define UDRE 5
#endif

#ifndef RXC
#define RXC 7
#endif

#define FRAMING_ERROR (1<<FE)
#define PARITY_ERROR (1<<UPE)
#define DATA_OVERRUN (1<<DOR)
#define DATA_REGISTER_EMPTY (1<<UDRE)
#define RX_COMPLETE (1<<RXC)

// Get a character from the USART Receiver
#ifndef _DEBUG_TERMINAL_IO_
#define _ALTERNATE_GETCHAR_
#pragma used+
char getchar(void)
{
char status,data;
while (1)
{
while (((status=UCSRA) & RX_COMPLETE)==0);
data=UDR;
if ((status & (FRAMING_ERROR | PARITY_ERROR | DATA_OVERRUN))==0)
return data;
}
}
#pragma used-
#endif

// Write a character to the USART Transmitter
#ifndef _DEBUG_TERMINAL_IO_
#define _ALTERNATE_PUTCHAR_
#pragma used+
void putchar(char c)
{
while ((UCSRA & DATA_REGISTER_EMPTY)==0);
UDR=c;
}
#pragma used-
#endif

// Standard Input/Output functions
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int adc_data;
#define ADC_VREF_TYPE 0x40

// ADC interrupt service routine
interrupt [ADC_INT] void adc_isr(void)
{
// Read the AD conversion result
adc_data=ADCW;
}

// Read the AD conversion result
// with noise canceling
unsigned int read_adc(unsigned char adc_input)
{
ADMUX=adc_input | (ADC_VREF_TYPE & 0xff);
// Delay needed for the stabilization of the ADC input voltage
delay_us(10);
#asm
in r30,mcucr
cbr r30,__sm_mask
sbr r30,__se_bit | __sm_adc_noise_red
out mcucr,r30
sleep
cbr r30,__se_bit
out mcucr,r30
#endasm
return adc_data;
}

int knob1,knob2;
float y;


void main(void)
{
// Declare your local variables here

// Input/Output Ports initialization
// Port A initialization
// Func7=In Func6=In Func5=In Func4=In Func3=In Func2=In Func1=In Func0=In
// State7=T State6=T State5=T State4=T State3=T State2=T State1=T State0=T
PORTA=0x00;
DDRA=0x00;

// Port B initialization
// Func7=In Func6=In Func5=In Func4=In Func3=In Func2=Out Func1=Out Func0=Out
// State7=T State6=T State5=T State4=T State3=T State2=0 State1=0 State0=0
PORTB=0x00;
DDRB=0x07;

// Port C initialization
// Func7=In Func6=In Func5=In Func4=In Func3=In Func2=In Func1=In Func0=In
// State7=T State6=T State5=T State4=T State3=T State2=T State1=T State0=T
PORTC=0x00;
DDRC=0x00;

// Port D initialization
// Func7=In Func6=In Func5=In Func4=In Func3=In Func2=In Func1=In Func0=In
// State7=T State6=T State5=T State4=T State3=T State2=T State1=T State0=T
PORTD=0x00;
DDRD=0x00;

// Timer/Counter 0 initialization
// Clock source: System Clock
// Clock value: Timer 0 Stopped
// Mode: Normal top=0xFF
// OC0 output: Disconnected
TCCR0=0x00;
TCNT0=0x00;
OCR0=0x00;

// Timer/Counter 1 initialization
// Clock source: System Clock
// Clock value: Timer1 Stopped
// Mode: Normal top=0xFFFF
// OC1A output: Discon.
// OC1B output: Discon.
// Noise Canceler: Off
// Input Capture on Falling Edge
// Timer1 Overflow Interrupt: Off
// Input Capture Interrupt: Off
// Compare A Match Interrupt: Off
// Compare B Match Interrupt: Off
TCCR1A=0x00;
TCCR1B=0x00;
TCNT1H=0x00;
TCNT1L=0x00;
ICR1H=0x00;
ICR1L=0x00;
OCR1AH=0x00;
OCR1AL=0x00;
OCR1BH=0x00;
OCR1BL=0x00;

// Timer/Counter 2 initialization
// Clock source: System Clock
// Clock value: Timer2 Stopped
// Mode: Normal top=0xFF
// OC2 output: Disconnected
ASSR=0x00;
TCCR2=0x00;
TCNT2=0x00;
OCR2=0x00;

// External Interrupt(s) initialization
// INT0: Off
// INT1: Off
// INT2: Off
MCUCR=0x00;
MCUCSR=0x00;

// Timer(s)/Counter(s) Interrupt(s) initialization
TIMSK=0x00;

// USART initialization
// Communication Parameters: 8 Data, 1 Stop, Even Parity
// USART Receiver: On
// USART Transmitter: On
// USART Mode: Asynchronous
// USART Baud Rate: 9600
UCSRA=0x00;
UCSRB=0x18;
UCSRC=0xA6;
UBRRH=0x00;
UBRRL=0x67;

// Analog Comparator initialization
// Analog Comparator: Off
// Analog Comparator Input Capture by Timer/Counter 1: Off
ACSR=0x80;
SFIOR=0x00;

// ADC initialization
// ADC Clock frequency: 125/000 kHz
// ADC Voltage Reference: AVCC pin
// ADC Auto Trigger Source: ADC Stopped
ADMUX=ADC_VREF_TYPE & 0xff;
ADCSRA=0x8F;

// SPI initialization
// SPI disabled
SPCR=0x00;

// TWI initialization
// TWI disabled
TWCR=0x00;

// Global enable interrupts
#asm("sei")

while (1)
{
PORTB.0=0;
PORTB.1=0;
PORTB.2=0;
delay_ms(30);
y=read_adc(0);
knob1=(y/1023)*127;
printf(" knob1= ");
printf("%d",knob1);

PORTB.0=0;
PORTB.1=0;
PORTB.2=1;
delay_ms(30);
y=read_adc(0);
knob2=(y/1023)*127;
delay_ms(1000);
printf(" knob2= ");
printf("%d",knob2);
delay_ms(1000);
}
}
```

And this is the output (I have already set the knobs to 127):
[image: output]

Comment: This forum software doesn't use "code" tags, so I have edited your question.

Comment: Where does noise come? Try and be as specific as you can, take a minute or so to think about an answer. Oh, it's the multiplexer - you are not giving enough time for  the signal to settle after switching between channels. Read the data sheet.

Comment: really ! thanks , actually i don't know too mutch about electeronic
my multiplexer  is CD4051BE how mutch time should i give to this

Comment: Why do you think looking at the software would help? Did you check your signals with an oscilloscope?

Answer (score 1):

probably it's a hard ware problem, is there a capacitor on Vref input, a resistor form Vcc to AVcc and capacitor form AVCC to GND ?, Is ADC inputs far from noisy signals ? it's better to use the internal Vref rater than AVCC. 
try to connect 2 ADC inputs together and try converting each one then compare the results.

Comment: Maybe a interrupt wake up the mcu before end of conversion.
Try in read_adc : 
do 
  {sleep ;} 
while (!(ADCSRA & ADIF)) }  ; 
ADCSRA &= 1<<ADIF ;

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer?

Comment: no, it is not !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers

I have made a lot of changes :

I put off the multiplexer and completely changed the code

> Why do you think looking at the software would help? Did you check your signals with an oscilloscope?

I don't check the circuit with oscilloscope beacuse i don't have an oscilloscope 
just checked with multimeter

> probably it's a hard ware problem, is there a capacitor on Vref input, a resistor form Vcc to AVcc and capacitor form AVCC to GND ?, Is ADC inputs far from noisy signals ? it's better to use the internal Vref rater than AVCC. try to connect 2 ADC inputs together and try converting each one then compare the results.

This is the circuit :

[circuit](http://uppic.com/uploads/14450789451.jpg)

and this is the code :

```
//my global variables :
```

```
int noisereduction(int ADC);
void send(int x);
int knob1,knob2,array[2],copyarray[2],c[2]={30,30},index=0,i;
while (1)
{
  knob1=noisereduction(0);
  array[0]=knob1; 
  knob2=noisereduction(1);
  array[1]=knob2;        
  for(i=0;i<2;i++)
  {
   if (array[i]!=copyarray[i])
   {
    c[index]=i;
    index++;
   } 
  }     
  for(i=0;i<2;i++)
  if(c[i]!=30)
  {
   index=c[i];
   switch (index)
   { 
     case 0:
     {
      delay_ms(50);
      printf(" knob1= ");
      printf("%d",array[index]);
     }
     case 1:
     { 
      delay_ms(50);
      printf(" knob2= ");
      printf("%d",array[index]);
   }
 }
```

}

```
index=0;    
for(i=0;i<2;i++)
{
 c[i]=30;
  copyarray[i]=array[i];
}
```

}

```
int noisereduction(int ADC)
{
 int sum=0,x,reduction[4],i;
 float y;
 sum=0;
 for(i=0;i<4;i++)
 {
   delay_ms(30);
   y=read_adc(ADC);
   x=(y/1023)*127;
   reduction[i]=x;
   sum=sum+reduction[i];
 }
 return sum/=4;
```

}

`void send(int x)
{
  int y;
  y=UCSRA & 0b00100000; 
  while(y != 0b00100000)
  {
    y=UCSRA & 0b00100000;
  }
  UDR=x; 
}`

but the output :

when i change the second Potentiometer (ADC(1) or knob2)
erery thing is good

[knob2](http://www.uppic.com/uploads/14450795701.jpg)

but noise is come :D when i change the first Potentiometer (ADC(0) or knob1)
why the knob 2 is changing when i even not touch that , it's making me crazy :D

output : knob1=1 knob2=1 knob1=5 knob2=5 knob1 =8 knob2=8 knob1=10 knob2=10 ..etc

Comment: I tried my best to edit your answer. Links to the circuit are missing.!

Comment: thanks you are the best .

http://www.uppic.com/uploads/14450789451.jpg =circuit